# How to configure pam to only mount with winbind authentification

Tags: active-directory, ldap, samba, mount, pam

I'm trying to configure pam with the following requests :

- You can log with local account(root, local users)
- You can log with AD accounts and if you do, pam mount home share
- You can log with AD account through cache credentials (ccreds)  if AD isn't accessible, and if you do, pam don't try to mount home share

So far I almost manage to configure pam that way but when I log on AD account when it isn't accessible, pam is trying to mount home share which isn't accessible as well.

I think I got how pam config files works and I tested a lot of different things, So if an pam expert would like to help I'll be very thankful

Here are the pam config files :

/etc/pam.d/common-auth

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=4 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_winbind.so krb5_auth         krb5_ccache_type=FILE cached_login try_first_pass
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_ccreds.so minimum_uid=1000 action=validate use_first_pass
#               auth    [success=2 default=ignore]              pam_ccreds.so minimum_uid=1000 action=update
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    optional                        pam_mount.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional                        pam_ccreds.so minimum_uid=1000 action=store
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

/etc/pam.d/common-session

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
session [default=1]                     pam_permit.so
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
session requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
session required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
session required                        pam_unix.so
session [success=ok default=1]          pam_winbind.so
session [success=done default=ignore]   pam_mount.so
session sufficient                      pam_ccreds.so
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninterractive

```
session [default=1]                     pam_permit.so
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
session requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
session required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
session required        pam_unix.so
session sufficient      pam_ccreds.so
```

If you need more information don't hesitate to ask. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm trying to debug the authentication thanks to  pam_exec.so by writing my "own" log and I find out that the winbind.so module is the source of my problems. It seems like that winbind.so recognize the user and try to log him through AD. I need to have a timeout with this step. Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to do what I wanted to do using pam_exec.so module to check if the ActiveDirectory server was joinable or not.
Here are the pam files :

/etc/pam.d/common-auth

```
 auth    optional                        pam_exec.so log=/var/tmp/pam.log  /bin/echo "-----AUTH------"
auth    [success=5 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [success=3 authinfo_unavail=ignore  default=1]  pam_winbind.so krb5_auth krb5_ccache_type=FILE cached_login try_first_pass
auth    [success=4 default=ignore]      pam_ccreds.so minimum_uid=1000 action=validate use_first_pass
auth    [success=die default=die]               pam_ccreds.so minimum_uid=1000 action=update
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    [success=1 default=die]                 pam_ccreds.so minimum_uid=1000 action=store
auth    [success=4 default=die]                  pam_exec.so log=/var/tmp/pam.log  /bin/echo "sucessfully log with unix"
session [success=ok default=2]          pam_exec.so log=/var/tmp/script.log  /bin/ping  -c 1 ipaddress.to.AD.server
auth    optional        pam_mount.so
auth    [success=1 default=die]                  pam_exec.so log=/var/tmp/pam.log  /bin/echo "sucessfully log with winbind"
auth    [default=die]                            pam_exec.so log=/var/tmp/pam.log  /bin/echo "sucessfully log with ccreds"
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
```

/etc/pam.d/common-account

```
account optional                        pam_exec.so log=/var/tmp/pam.log  /bin/echo "-----ACCOUNT------"
account [success=ok new_authtok_reqd=done default=1]    pam_unix.so
account [success=3]                     pam_exec.so log=/var/tmp/pam.log  /bin/echo "Logged with Unix account"
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_winbind.so
account requisite                       pam_deny.so
account optional                        pam_exec.so log=/var/tmp/pam.log  /bin/echo "Logged with winbind account"
account required                        pam_permit.so
```

/etc/pam.d/common-session

```
session    optional                             pam_exec.so log=/var/tmp/pam.log  /bin/echo "-----SESSION------"
session [default=1]                     pam_permit.so
session requisite                       pam_deny.so
session required                        pam_permit.so
session [success=ok default=1]  pam_unix.so
session [success=ok]            pam_exec.so log=/var/tmp/pam.log  /bin/echo "unix session started"
session [success=ok default=die]        pam_winbind.so
session required        pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0077
session [success=ok default=2]          pam_exec.so log=/var/tmp/script.log  /bin/ping  -c 1 ipaddress.to.AD.server
session optional        pam_mount.so
session [success=done]  pam_exec.so log=/var/tmp/pam.log  /bin/echo "winbind session started + homedir mounted"
session optional        pam_exec.so log=/var/tmp/pam.log  /bin/echo "ccreds session started"
```

You just have to change the IP address in auth and session file to get it working. You will have personalized log in /var/tmp/ for the pings and echos.
I think there are better solutions than mine to resolve that problem but I didn't find it.

Hope these conf files will help some people!